# How do I change Url first part after getting the currentUrl in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a function where it reads emails from DB and stores it on the desktop.

That email is for password reset email. The url is always pointed to Prod even in Test. I need to replace the first part of the string to -test. How can I achieve this?

```
     browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(CurrentUrl) {
   var modifyUrl = CurrentUrl;// Getting current url 

   console.log(modifyUrl);//This one has the current Url

//The modifyUrl looks like this  https://login.domain.com/reset/####..
//I want to replace just login to login-test
// I tried the following but I am getting Window is undefined message.

var URL = window(modifyUrl).location.toString();
window.location = URL.replace(/login/, 'login-test')

 });
```

Appreciate help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have *direct* access to the `window` object in your test (you can though access it through the `browser.executeScript()` if needed).

Instead of modifying `window.location`, use [`browser.get()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.get):

```
var url = CurrentUrl.replace(/login\.domain\.com/, 'login-test.domain.com');
browser.get(url);
```

I've also improved your replacement logic a bit, to avoid having `login` replaced in other parts of the URL.

Comment: Thanks a bunchhhhhhhhhh... Worked. :)